# Xamarin.ActionbarSherlockBinding.App.ActionBar.ITabListener and SearchView

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

i am still pretty new to xamarin and I downloaded a sample app.

When i tried to build it, 2 issues occured
1. There's no reference for Xamarin.ActionbarSherlockBinding.App.ActionBar.ITabListener

2. There's no reference for
   Xamarin.ActionbarSherlockBinding.Widget.SearchView

I tried to google the error but unable to find any relevant post. the screenshot is the configuration of my xamarin. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to use ActionbarSherlock? It is deprecated and replaced by Toolbar.

Comment: I don't know that it has been deprecated. OK i will try too use toolbar thx. How about searchview? has it been deprecated? if yes, may i know what's the substitute? thx